# Declared a List, Implement as LinkedList, cannot use getLast() method

Tags: casting

I'm tried to create a linkedlist like below

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
int i = list.getLast();
```

But when I use getLast() method from LinkedList class, it reports "cannot find symbol "method getLast()"".

It appears that, since getLast() only exists in LinkedList class, and I declared list as a List, so I cast it into a more general form and lost some function.

But I'm curious how Java find a method name? Since I instantiate it as a LinkedList, can't it find this method in instantiated class?
Is there any documents I can read about

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `List` interface does not expose a `getLast()` method, which is particular to the implementation `LinkedList`.  You have several options here.  If you want to declare your `List` as just that, then you may cast the linked list variable before calling `getLast()`:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(1);
int i = ((LinkedList<Integer>)list).getLast();  // but make sure it's a linked list
```

Another option would be to just declare your list as a linked list:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
```